# Disable swipe-to-open for Drawer in specific view

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm developing a web application with Kendo Mobile and using the Drawer widget as a menu. One of my views is a Google map and I'd like to disable the swipe-to-open feature of Kendo Mobile's Drawer when in this view, for obvious reasons...

I've tried the following :

#### Bind to the Drawer's beforeShow event

...and stop it from opening if the current view is the map view

```
    beforeShow: function (beforeShowEvt) {
        if(app.view().id == "#stationMap") {
            beforeShowEvt.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that it also trigger's (and prevents drawer from opening) when I click on the menu button in my top bar.

I've looked through the beforeShowEvt and can't seem to find anything to let me know if it was triggered via swipe of via menu click.

#### Bind to the Google maps containing div

...and catch touchstart events to stop them propagating up and being picked up by Kendo.

This hasn't worked at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved my problem :

1. Added an event handler to Google Map's `dragstart` event which sets a flag to true
2. Added an event handler to the Drawer button's `touchstart` event which sets this flag to false
3. Added a check in the Drawer's beforeShow event to see if flag is `true`, if it is I `preventDefault();`

Works like a charm!

Comment: On google maps view :
`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
    setDragFlag(true);
});`

On menu button's touchstart event : `$("a#drawerButton").bind("touchstart", function () {
                setDragFlag(false);
            });`

In drawer's beforeShow event :
`if(viewId == "#mapView" && isDragFlag()) {
    beforeShowEvt.preventDefault();
    return;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I know this isnt the real answer but I have a work around.  Just create a new .html file and put your google widget in that and then call it like so:

```
app.navigate("nodrawerwidgets.html");
```

OR

```
<a href="nodrawerwidgets.html">Google widget<a>
```

My first thought was to intercept the swipe actions by wrapping your widget in a div :

```
    <div id="divStopSwipe">
```

...

```
$("#divStopSwipe").kendoTouch({
  enableSwipe: true,
  swipe: function (e) { //do nothing or figure out how to let the action pass down to the widget
  }
});
```

..however this would stop the google widget from getting the swipe actions.

hope this helps a little - I am new to mobile ui as well.